# Adding column names to a .dat file in R as a new row

Tags: r

I am trying to work with a large Data Frame in R that was supplied to me as a .dat file. Unfortunately, the data file wasn't ideally formatted and thus I am having issues.

I can read the data file with:

```
myData <- read.delim(file=here("myData.dat"))
```

However, when I view the data frame it is using the first row of data as the headings. Due to the format of the file, I cannot edit it to add in appropriate headings directly to the file. I attempted to use:

```
colnames(myData) = (c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3"))
```

Except this replaces the data used for the column names, and hence essentially removes a row of the data set.

Attempting to use:

```
myData <- read.delim(file=here("myData.dat"), col.names(c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3"))
```

results in the error "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : more columns than column names".

Is there any way to add an entirely new row to use as the column names?

Side Note: The data I am working with is confidential and so I'm unable to share it. It has about 10,600 rows of data and 50 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default setting for the header (column names) in `read.delim` is set to TRUE. Therefore the function expects column names in the first row. You can enable that argument with `header = FALSE`, than your colnames will be V followed by the number of each column. Futhermore you can add your own column names with the `col.names` argument. Just make sure your list has a name for every column in your data frame (in your case 50 names). Otherwise you may get an error.

The code might look like this:

```
myData <- read.delim(file=here("myData.dat"),
                     header = FALSE, 
                     col.names = c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3"))
```

In your case with 50 columns, I would specify the names in an own object and add the object to the read.delim function. Like this:

```
my.names <- c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3")

myData <- read.delim(file=here("myData.dat"),
                     header = FALSE, 
                     col.names = my.names)
```